# Find query not showing results from referenced table in CakePHP using HABTM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a HABTM relationship between two models, Agents and Categories. I've followed the instructions here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

I've setup the tables, created the FKs, etc. In order to test to see if Categories are being retrieved for a find query on Agents I put in the following debug code:

```
debug($this->AgentsCategories->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('Agent.name', 'Agent.address'), 
    'conditions' => array('Agent.id' => '59')
)));
```

The resulting array:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Agent' => array(
            'id' => '59',
            'name' => 'MUTUAL UNDERWRITERS',
            'address' => 'Waipahu Branch
94-615 Kupuohi St #102
Waipahu, HI 96797',
            'telephone' => '808-688-2222',
            'fax' => '808-688-0769',
            'email' => null,
            'website' => 'http://www.mutualunderwriters.com',
            'island' => '1',
            'modified' => '2014-04-16 15:56:46'
        )
    )
)
```

only shows info from the Agents table, it doesn't show categories from the categories table where agents.id is a FK. From the instructions I would expect something like the example below:

```
Array
(
    [Recipe] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2745
            [name] => Chocolate Frosted Sugar Bombs
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
            [user_id] => 2346
        )
    [Ingredient] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [name] => Chocolate
                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [name] => Sugar
                )
           [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 125
                    [name] => Bombs
                )
        )
)
```

What am I doing wrong and/or how should I debug this? Thank you!

Comment: show your Agent Model code

Answer (score 0):

You Agent Model should looks like:

```
class Agent extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Category' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'joinTable' => 'agents_categories', //or your table name
            'foreignKey' => 'agent_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        )
);
}
```

And simply do a search like:

```
$this->Agent->find('all', array('order' => array('Agent.name', 'Agent.address'), 
                                'conditions' => array('Agent.id' => '59')));
```

You will get the expected result.

Comment: two words that should be in the answer `recursive` and `containable` =).

Comment: Thanks for the help, my Agent Model looks like that and the query looks like that too but the output doesn't match the example whereby no Category array is shown.

Comment: Hi @AD7six, what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: @dev808 [recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) is used to broadly control what a find call returns. [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) offers much finer control - they are "the answer" and without them an answer is incomplete.